# Is there a name for the set of bit combinations of bitstrings?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, combinations, binary

Let $A \subset \{0,1\}^n$ be a set of $n$-bit bit vectors.  Let me call a bit vector $b = (b^{(1)}, b^{(2)}, \dotsc, b^{(n)}) \in \{0,1\}^n$ a "bit combination" of the vectors in $A$ if: $$\forall i \in \{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}\ \exists a_i \in A: b^{(i)} = a_i^{(i)}.$$

That is, $b$ is a "bit combination" of the bit vectors in $A$ if and only if each bit of $b$ matches the corresponding bit of at least one bit vector in $A$.

> Is there an accepted name for such a bit vector $b$, or for the set $B_A \subset \{0,1\}^n$ of all such bit vectors?

Geometrically, identifying $\{0,1\}^n$ with the vertices of an $n$-dimensional hypercube, $B_A$ is the smallest sub-hypercube of $\{0,1\}^n$ that contains all the vertices in $A$.  Intuitively, this concept would seem sort of analogous to that of the [convex hull](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull), except that, instead of convex combinations, we have "bit combinations" as defined above.  It seems like something that should have a name, but I can't seem to find one.

Ps. For what it's worth, this question arose while I was writing [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/lamport-signature-how-many-signatures-are-need-to-forge-a-signature/15246#15246) about forging [Lamport one-time signatures](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature) on crypto.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a bitstring $a$, you can consider its **graph** $$\newcommand{\graph}{\operatorname{graph}}\graph a := \{ (k, a_k) : k \in [n] \} \subset [n] \times \{0,1\}.$$
Here $[n] := \{1,2,\dots, n\}$.
(For a formal set theory point of view, $a$ and $\graph a$ are actually the same object.)

Then your condition reads
$$\graph b \subset \bigcup_{a \in A} \graph a.$$

Comment: Huh... so, once I've explained that a bitstring may be represented as a vector, which may be represented as a function from $\{1, 2, \dotsc, n\}$ to $\{0,1\}$, which may be identified with is graph... I could simply write $b \subset \bigcup A$.  Nice, even if somewhat liable to confuse a more applied-math oriented audience.  If someone doesn't come up with an even better answer, I'll accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

Your "bit combination" vectors can be interpreted as so-called choice functions in the context of set theory. Maybe that is not exactly what you're asking for, but the similarity is overwhelming.

More precise:
Let us at first transform your set $A$ into $n$ sets $A_{i}$, where each set $A_{i}$ contains the $i$-th bits of all vectors in $A$. For example $A_{1}$ contains every (different) first bit of all vectors in $A$. With this definition we can interpret your "bit combination" vector as a choice function of those sets $A_{i}$ and the set $B_{A}$ can be interpreted as the set of all possible choice functions to the sets $A_{i}$.

Comment: Thanks! Alas, the doesn't seem to really get me much closer to what I'm looking for, i.e. a convenient way to say "$b$ is in the __________ of $A$".